# What type of bolts are suitable for a turbo exhaust housing?

Tags: turbocharger, heat, bolts, steel

Whilst removing the exhaust housing from my Garrett GT28R turbo, the thread of the bolts sheared off and needs replacing.

[image: example]

It's a blackened bolt, so I'm not sure if this has any significance? (heat resistant coating?).
My question is can I replace these bolts with standard zinc plated grade 8.8 or grade 10 steel bolts? Or do they need to be some kind of heat resistant bolt/coating?

Thanks!

Comment: grade 10, and use high temp anti-seize on the threads.

Comment: is there a risk of the anti-seize helping the bolts come loose over time?

Comment: @SeanChapman anti-seize does not mean “come loose” unless you left it loose in the first place.

Comment: "is there a risk of the anti-seize helping the bolts come loose over time" not if torqued properly.

Answer (score 1):

Any zinc coating is a serious NO ( liquid metal -steel- embrittlement risk of stressed component like a bolt). The exhaust components can get pretty hot . Any standard steel bolting ( eg.chrome moly ) is going to start relaxing at 800 F, I think design temperatures are well above that. [relaxing comes at lower temperature than creeping]. I expect they are nickel alloy , there are a bunch so not worth listing them . And ,you  only can get what is available in the automotive world, So you need to check with manufacturers or re-conditioners. Or , I can promise you that MP-35N would be great,Standard Pressed Steel , Jenkinstown PA , or Rolled Alloys . ...Just stick with manufacturer and reconditioners.